# Do we need to overload == operator if I have overloaded <?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an object of custom type A (a class that has many members which are std::string, vectors etc but no raw pointers).

Now, I have a list of A objects.

```
A tmpobj;  
std::list<A> temp;
```

If I want to invoke std::list::remove function to remove a specific object from the list
I am trying

```
temp.remove(tmpobj)
```

Now, here are my questions

1. I am assuming i need to overload == operator. Please let me know
   if I dont need to and if the default == will work. I am not sure
   about that. I know it would work if I did not have any STL based
   members
2. I already have the < operator overloaded. Yet, I think
   "==" operator needs to be provided. Is this right. One argument can
   be, we can determine "==" as two calls to '<' operator like

   if(a < b || b < a) 
       return false 
   else 
       return true;

Or is this not done because its inefficient to do 2 calls or is there any other reason for that.

Comment: Doesit mean the issue is because I have overloaded <, thre is an ambiguity between default "==" and the one that could be derived from '<'. Otherwise, if there is '<' would it go the default '=='?

Comment: `operator==` can be far more effective than twice `operator<`. E.g. for string equality you can quickly compare `left.size() == right.size()`. This doesn't help at all for string ordering.

Comment: There is no ambiguity, but you have to make sure you define all comparison operators in a consistent manner. And you should know which containers and which algorithms require which types of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

n3337 23.3.5.5

```
void remove(const T& value);

template <class Predicate> void remove_if(Predicate pred);
```

> Effects: Erases all the elements in the list referred by a list iterator i for which the following conditions
>     hold: ***i == value**, **pred(*i) != false**. Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased
>    elements.

So, you need overloaded `operator ==` or predicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default `operator==`, so don't worry about that. When the compiler complains that your class has no `operator==`, implement it ;-)

If all the possible values of your class together represent a set with the mathematical property of being "totally ordered", then you could implement `operator==` in terms of `operator<`. It's not necessarily the most efficient way, but the main reason that C++ doesn't assume it is that in general it doesn't assume anything about how different overloaded operators should relate to one another. Not all types necessarily represent totally-ordered sets. For better or worse, C++ lets you use `operator<` to represent a partial order.

Comment: Try and error programming can easily lead to portability issues. Compilers might have different ideas how to implement something if the standard doesn't specify it. Maybe there is an optional fall-back (which uses `operator<` if there is no `operator==`) in *your* compiler but not in another compiler (or another library, for that matter).

Comment: @bitmask: the standard forbids any such "fall-back", when it defines how `list::remove` works. `set::find`, on the other hand, does use `operator<` and never `operator==`, again this is defined. Another possibility is that the user's type `A` might have an implicit conversion to some type that does have a non-member `operator==`. In that case, `list::remove` will compile (as will the expression `a == b` where they're both of type `A`), and may or may not have the behavior the questioner wants. So I'm joking (hence the smiley) to the extent that this is a real risk.

Comment: @SteveJessop, when you say there is no default '==' operator, does it mean i cannot use obectA==objectB for a custom defined class. I was thinking, there is always a bit by bit comparison (which i was referring to as default '=='.  Please correct me if I have incorrectly understood.

Comment: @AMM: there is no bit by bit comparison.

Comment: @AMM No. there is no default `operator ==` for custom class (if there is no implicit conversion operator).